# Can inclusion of specific fields change the elasticsearch result set?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES query that returns 414 documents if I exclude a specific field from results.

If I include this field, the document count drops to 328.

The documents that get dropped are consistent and this happens whether I scroll results or query directly.

The field map for the field that reduces the result set looks like this:

```
"completion": {
     "type": "object",
     "enabled": false
}
```

Nothing special to it and I have other "enabled": false object type fields that return just fine in this query.

I tested against multiple indexes with the same data to rule out corruption (I hope).

This 'completion' object is a nested and ignored object that has 4 or 5 levels of nesting but once again, I have other similarly nested objects that return just fine for this query.

The query is a simple terms match for 414 terms (yes, this is terrible, we are rethinking our strategy on this):

```
  var { _scroll_id, hits } = await elastic.search({
    index: index,
    type: type,
    body: shaQuery,
    scroll: '10s',
    _source_exclude: 'account,layout,surveydata,verificationdata,accounts,scores'
  });
  while (hits && hits.hits.length) {
    // Append all new hits
    allRecords.push(...hits.hits)

    var { _scroll_id, hits } = await elastic.scroll({
      scrollId: _scroll_id,
      scroll: '10s'
    })
  }
```

The query is:

```
"query": {
        "terms": {
            "_id": [
                "....",
                "....",
                "...."
            }
        }
}
```

In this example, I will only get back 328 results. If I add 'completion' to the _source_exclude then I get the full set back.

So, my question is: What are the scenarios where including a field in the result could limit the search when that field is totally unrelated to the search.

The #'s are specific to this example but consistent across queries. I just include them for context on the overall problem.

Also important is that this completion field has the same data and format across both included and excluded records, I can't see anything that would cause a problem.

Comment: Can you add a sample document which was a part of result before adding the field and once the field is added it is not returned in result?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was found and it was obscure. What we saw was that it was always failing at the same point and when it was examined a little more closely, the same error was coming out:

```
{ took: 158,
 timed_out: false,
 _shards:
  { total: 5,
    successful: 4,
    skipped: 0,
    failed: 1,
    failures: [ [Object] ] },
[ { shard: 0,
   index: ‘theindexname’,
   node: ‘4X2vwouIRriYbQTQcHQ_sw’,
   reason:
    { type: ‘illegal_argument_exception’,
      reason:
       ‘cannot write xcontent for unknown value of type class java.math.BigInteger’ } } ]
```

Ok well thats strange, we are not using BigIntegers at all. But, thanks to the power of the Google this issue in the elasticsearch issue tracker was revealed:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/32888

"XContentBuilder to handle BigInteger and BigDecimal" which is a bug in 6.3 where fields that used BigInteger and BigDecimal would fail to serialize and thus break when source filtering was applied. We were running 6.3.

It is unclear why our systems are triggering this issue but upgrading to 6.5 solved it entirely.

Obscure obscure obscure but solved thanks to [Javier's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247462/javier-ferrero) persistence.